# PostgreSQL query by string is filtering even the values where there are nulls.

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I've created a table in PostgreSQL 9.5 as shown below and I added some data to it. However, when I try and query data by case insensitive search like !~* it removes even the null value rows. How can I do a query that will return all categories that are null and vegetables but not fruits?

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
  category character varying,
  item character varying
);

INSERT INTO temp VALUES('Fruits', 'apple');
INSERT INTO temp VALUES('FRUITS', 'applE');
INSERT INTO temp(item) VALUES('Apple');
INSERT INTO temp(item) VALUES('BANANA');
INSERT INTO temp VALUES('Vegetables', 'Cabbage');
```

**Query**

```
Select * from temp where category !~* 'fruits'
```

**Output**

```
category   item
--------   --------
Vegetables Cabbage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with the null you can use `is distinct from`:

```
Select * 
from temp 
where lower(category) is distinct from 'fruits'
```

or if you do want the regular expression:

```
Select * 
from temp 
where category !~* 'fruits'
  or category is null;
```

alternatively treat null as something else:

```
Select * 
from temp 
where coalesce(category, '') !~* 'fruits'
```

Comment: However, if I  tried to nest and/or join the query those nulls disappear. In this case for instance: Select * from (
Select * 
from temp 
where category !~* 'fruits'
  or category is null
) "t" 
where "category" !~* 'vegetables'

Comment: However if I do coalesce then it works: Select * from (
Select * 
from temp 
where coalesce(category,'') !~* 'fruits'
  
) "t" 
where coalesce("category",'') !~* 'vegetables'